# Antlr parsers for target language Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, antlr, antlr4

Can someone link me to an antlr parser already made for python2.
I need to parse python code for variables extraction in any python program.

Comment: SO is great for getting help, but you'll have to ask a specific question first. Yours, as it is right now, is too broad. Have a look at how questions ought to be asked here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the python `parser` or `ast` modules [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html?highlight=parser#module-parser)
They might be useful.